# How To Move All Selected Objects To A Specific Z Value?

Tags: objects, coordinates

Currently if I select a group of object and change the Z value it only move the object I originally selected. Is it possible to change the coordinates of a certain selection of objects of different Z values to all the same Z values without changing the x or y values. In addition to this can you change the selection of objects height without changing their width or length. If either of these are possible then how is it possible. If possible could you tell me in the simplest way possible as I don't know much about blender.

Comment: hold ctrl while clicking the z value, then enter a number. Just change e.g. scale z value while holding ctrl. Hint: you should watch some beginner tutorials. These here are free and good: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Comment: You need to hold ALT while clicking on the Z value!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> whilst having a group of objects selected then change the Z value then it will set all selected objects to that Z coordinate but keep all of the other coordinates the same.

Answer (score 4):

Place one of the objects at the height you need.  Then select all the objects again, making sure you select the "right height object" last so that it's the active one.
Then go to Object/Transform/Align Objects, and activate Z axis.